# I have a 2009 MacBook Air, bought a year ago - will I notice much of a performance improvement if I buy the latest version (Late 2010)?

Tags: upgrade, macbook-pro

Does the SSD make that much difference? The processor is not much beefier, what are the other factors I should consider/which have an impact? Anyone made the same upgrade and happy with a significant improvement? Or am I just wanting a new shiny thing?

Comment: Yes, the SSD does make a huge difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flash storage makes a huge difference (a fresh system boots in about 15 seconds, apps will start instantly etc.), and the new MBA does not need to throttle the CPU when it gets hot. So you will probably notice a big improvement. See [Macworlds benchmark results](http://www.macworld.com/article/154596/2010/10/macbookair_benchmarks.html), for example.